# How can we evaluate the following CDF?

Tags: probability, cumulative-distribution-function, convolution

First let us consider the following regression
\begin{equation}
y_t=\beta'x_t+\varepsilon_t,\quad t=1,...,n
\end{equation}

where $x_t$ is a $k\times 1$ vector of "fixed" regressors and $\beta$ is respectively a $k\times 1$ vector of coefficients. Thus for $t=1,...,n$, a CDF of the form
\begin{equation}
P[y_t\geq 0]
\end{equation}
can be evaluated as follows
\begin{eqnarray}
P[y_t\geq 0]&=&P[\beta'x_{t}+\varepsilon_t\geq0]\\
&=&P[\varepsilon_t\geq -\beta'x_{t}]\\
&=&1-P[\varepsilon_t< -\beta'x_{t}]
\end{eqnarray}
and when $\varepsilon_t \sim N(0,1)$, this can be evaluated using $\Phi(\beta'x_t)$. Now consider the case where $x_t$ is "stochastic", and such the second argument $P[\varepsilon_t\geq -\beta'x_{t}]$ no longer makes sense. How may we evaluate of a CDF of the form

\begin{eqnarray}
P[y_t\geq 0]&=&P[\beta'x_{t}+\varepsilon_t\geq0]\\
\end{eqnarray}

I have thought about using deconvolutions to decompose the latter terms, though I am not sure what is the correct way to go about this and also if $x_t$ is endogenous (i.e. $\mathbb{E}(\varepsilon_t x_t)\neq0)$, deconvolutions would not work. I look forward to suggestions.

Comment: What about$$\mathbb E^{X_t}[\Phi(\beta'X_t)]$$